How to use a function to change a timestamp
I need a function for a column to change from time stamp without time zone to date: but it has to be in function form.
I have tried many many things but no luck. I am completely stuck and lost on where to even start.
I also can’t seem to figure out how to call when creating a table.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_data_type (recruit TEXT, recruit_date TEXT, data TEXT)
RETURNS RECRUIT AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN DATE(recruit_date) FROM recruit;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


What do you mean with "I also can’t seem to figure out how to call when creating a table."? A date and a timestamp are 2 different data types. So if you want to have a date instead of a TS, just create a table with a date. You don't create a table with a TS then change the column to make it look like a date using a function or anything else. Can you please clarify your issue? Your question seems to address two different things: one is formatting or converting a TS with TZ to a date and a second one is creating a table that uses a date instead of a TS, but using your function for some reason.

Also, please explain your function. You talk about dates and timestamps, but all of them are text. What is recruit, recruit_date (which seems to be text, so what is its format?) and what is data? Why do you return RECRUIT in it? Provide a MRE and if you do have any errors, show them to us and maybe even a few examples of an input and the desired outputs. Also detail if you need formatting a date or converting it.

Select timestamp_fld::date

"but it has to be in function form" I can't think of a good reason for that requirement. Just use a cast.

Just cast the timestamp to a date and you're done. You could add some overhead by creating a function that does the casting, but that's just overhead and no additional functionality. SELECT CAST(recruit_date AS date) FROM recruit;
